# Removing all duplicate members from a list in scheme

Tags: scheme

I am trying to remove duplicates in a list, using recursion. This is what I have. It only removes the first duplicate, not all of them.

My idea is to look at the first member, check if its a member of the rest of the list, if so, call the function again. If not, create a list with the first member and the result from calling the function again. I don't understand why it doesn't  remove all the duplicates.

```
(define (removeDupes L)
  (cond ((null? L) ())
        ((list? (member (car L) (cdr L))) removeDupes (cdr L))
        (#T (cons ((car L) (removeDupes (cdr L)))))))
```

This is what I modified it to, and it works!! And I understand what was wrong with the cons. It needs two parameters and I only gave it one. I still have no Idea why the third line did not work....

```
(define (removeDupes L)
  (cond ((null? L) ())
        ((list? (member (car L) (cdr L)))(removeDupes(cdr L)))
        (#T (cons (car L) (removeDupes (cdr L))))))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are multiple errors in your code, but the one that's probably causing the problem you've reported here is that your parentheses are wrong in the third line. You're trying to call `removeDupes` but your code doesn't actually do so; instead the value in that case ends up being `(cdr L)`. Can you see why?

When you fix this, you'll find that your code starts producing errors. For the one you're likely to encounter first: take a careful look at how you're invoking `cons` on the last line. For the one you're likely to encounter next: remember that `()` is not self-evaluating in Scheme.

(I think this sort of thing is much harder to miss if you take care with the spacing and layout of your code. Put spaces between the elements of every list, for instance. Until you get so familiar with this stuff that these mistakes stop happening, you might want to make a habit of checking the parentheses any time you run across a mysterious error: have you missed a `(` at the start of an expression, or put an extra `(` before the arguments of a function, or forgotten the extra level of parens round a `cond` clause, or etc. etc. etc. Don't worry: after a while it'll stop happening...)

Comment: I've fixed the formatting, but not any of the things that are really bogus, of course. :-)

Comment: Re your edit: I highly recommend [Paredit](http://mumble.net/~campbell/emacs/paredit.html) for doing any sort of Lisp and Scheme coding. It ensures that brackets are always balanced at all times, among many other useful features.

Comment: OK, so you fixed all the bugs. It's a bit worrying that you have no idea why it helped, though! Perhaps you're missing the following Very Important Thing: parentheses in Scheme do not play *at all* the same sort of role as parentheses in mathematics. `((x))` is not remotely the same thing as `(x)`, which is not remotely the same thing as `x`. In general, in Scheme code a list `(a b c d)` means: call the function `a` with `b`,`c`,`d` as arguments. If you turn that into `((a b c d))` or `(a (b c) d)` or something, the meaning is completely different.

Comment: What is the diffrence beatween ((x)) and (x)? They mean the same thin don<t they... In this example (a (b c) d) function a is called after calling function b, with parameter c, which also has parameter d. I get that, thanks. But with cond((null? a) a b) which is kinda what I had at first...the condition is met, so then it looks for a function which is a, then looks for parameters which is b, no?

Comment: No no no no, `((x))` and `(x)` absolutely do not mean the same thing. To evaluate `(x)`, you find the value of `x`; it should be a function; you call that function; and that's the result. To evaluate `((x))`, you find the value of `(x)` -- and then *that* should be a function, and you call it to get the result. (This is admittedly hard to get your head around if you aren't used to functions that return functions that return functions!) [More on cond in a separate comment ...]

Comment: As for `cond`: that's a funny special case, because the clauses of a `cond` are one of the instances where `(x y)` *doesn't* mean "call x with y as argument". So, a cond clause `((null? x) a b)` means: if `(null? x)` evaluates to something true, then evaluate `a` and then `b`; the latter is the result. And `((null? x) (a b))` means: if `(null? x)` evaluates to something true, then evaluate `(a b)` and that's the result. To evaluate `(a b)`, you evaluate `a` (getting a function) and `b` (getting whatever you get), and call the function.

Comment: Incidentally, don't be discouraged if all this "evaluate this, evaluate that, call the other" stuff seems terribly confusing. You'll get used to it if you keep at it, I promise.